# Swift protocol delegate not being fired

Tags: ios, swift

I have a VC that contains a containerview that holds a table view.
**= Root VC holds the tableview**

I have setup a delegate from the tableview to the root VC that checks if the screen is being scrolled up or down, and this works.

What I now want to do is to have a delegate between root VC **to** the table view. When a button is clicked in the root VC I want to fire a function in the table view.

This will make the viewcontrollers have delegates implemented on each other - is that a problem?

eg:

```
class RootVC, tableViewDelegate
class Tableview, RootVCDelegate
```

My delegate looks like this:

```
protocol RootVCDelegate: class {
    func RootVCDidTouchGrid(controller: RootViewController)
}

class rootvc { ...

weak var delegate: RootVCDelegate?

@IBAction func gridButtonDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.RootVCDidTouchGrid(self)
    }
```

Then in table view:

```
class tableview, RootVCDelegate {..

func RootVCDidTouchGrid(controller: RootViewController) {
        println("touched!")
    }
```

So why is never `println("touched!")` fired?

Thanks

Comment: Stupid question but delegate has a value?

Comment: @Arsen I am setting: weak var delegate: RootVCDelegate?
Thats how I done it in other places and it works there

Answer (score 1):

1. You created the (weak) delegate property of type `RootVCDelegate` in your `RootViewController`
2. Your `TableView` class conforms to `RootVCDelegate`
3. You forgot to assign the `delegate` property of `RootViewController` to your `TableView` instance.

You're missing something like:

```
class tableview, RootVCDelegate {..

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        rootViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func RootVCDidTouchGrid(controller: RootViewController) {
        println("touched!")
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try that it says rootViewController does not have a member named delegate. I have done the exact same implementation in other places and it works, thats strange

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with tableview being inside a container view in RootViewController?
In RootViewController I am using the segue segue.identifier == "TableSegue". Could I pass the function there?

Comment: Not sure really, in your first post it's clear that rootVC does have a member named delegate. 

class rootvc { ...
weak var delegate: RootVCDelegate?
...

Comment: But in any case, if RootVC owns the Container, and the Container owns the TableView, then it's probably better for RootVC to tell the Container to tell the TableView that the grid was touched instead of using delegation.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that, since the embedded container view doesnt have a class/vc? The segue gets fired from RootVc

Comment: Can you explain what's your hierarchy? I'm a bit lost. So you have something like RootVC that pushes a TableVC? If that's the case then you can just hold a reference to the TableVC in your RootVC and call the method in TableVC directly when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

please define delegate value in view didload:

```
delegate = self
```

Comment: I have: weak var delegate: RootVCDelegate?
Thats how I done it in other vc's and it works

Comment: can you give me part of code so i can suggest you what's way

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to set a delegate. Just set it `delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I am: weak var delegate: RootVCDelegate?
Thats how I done it in other vc's and it works